# Strange webserver issue

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, webserver

MY OS: Ubuntu 12.10
Web server environment is: Nginx + PHP-FPM

Installed based [on this tutorial](http://iain.it/linux/how-to-install-php-fpm-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Here is nginx conf file of website

```
server {
set $host_path "path_to_website";

server_name  website.local;

root $host_path;
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

charset utf-8;
index index.php index.html;

log_not_found off;

location / {
    index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
    deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
    set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
    if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
        set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
```

}

BTW, this configuration is [optimized for Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config)

The problem is, when I try to enter to the website, getting following error:

```
File not found.
```

And when I open nginx `error.log` file, I see following content

```
    2013/03/22 23:36:45 [crit] 14388#0: *4 stat() "path_to_website" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: website.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "website.local"
2013/03/22 23:36:45 [crit] 14388#0: *4 stat() "path_to_website" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: website.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "website.local"
2013/03/22 23:36:45 [crit] 14388#0: *4 stat() "path_to_websiteindex.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: website.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "website.local"
2013/03/22 23:36:45 [error] 14388#0: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: website.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "website.local"
```

I'm 100% sure about path of website, and also added into hosts file `website.local`. Also `chown`-ed recursively whole parent directory recursively, where website located.

I can't figure out what can be problem. PLease help me to fix this problem. I can give remote acces to anyone who wants to help.

## NOTE

I just replaced the real path with this `path_to_website` for confidence. Thats all. THere is real path

Comment: why do you set $fsn but never use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 set $host_path "path_to_website";
```

you need to define what your path_to_website is:

ie: /var/www/

1. open terminal
2. List item
3. cd into the root of your www directory
4. type in 'pwd', and whatever it results
5. enter that into $host_path

Comment: 2013/03/22 23:36:45 [crit] 14388#0: *4 stat() "path_to_website" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: website.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "website.local"  .. it's showing path_to_website, not the actual location

Comment: I just replaced the real path with this `path_to_website` for confidence. Thats all. THere is real path

Comment: what are the permissions on that folder

Comment: I gave command chmod 755, and chown -x recursively starting from parent folder

Comment: If you are certain folder + host information are correct. Then I think the user which is running the ngnix process as a deamon doesn't have access. What does this return: ps aux | grep "nginx: worker process"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26746/discussion-between-heron-and-sajjad-merchant)

Comment: chown -R tural:www-data path_to_website

Comment: same error. nothing changed. can you please come to chatroom? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26746/discussion-between-heron-and-sajjad-merchant

Comment: give your IM, to be in touch with you, skype, gtalk anything?

Answer (score 0):

An nginx log file never lies. If it says it's a "Permission denied" error, then it is. You need to

- make sure this folder itself "path_to_website" is readable to the user www-data (which is the user running nginx based on your screenshot). One way to try this is to run this command in a terminal:

  ```
   sudo -u www-data ls path_to_website
  ```

and see if permission is denied for www-data or just

```
   ls -la path_to_website
```

to investigate that path's permission info.

- It is possible that a parent folder of your "path_to_website" is not accessible by user www-data. For example, if your path_to_website is "/var/www/mysite/", maybe "/var" or "/var/www" is not readable by www-data.